# How can I start designing my program on paper without over engineering things?

Tags: design-patterns, oop, uml, paradigms

I'm interested in starting to properly design my software on paper before I ever start coding. What is the standard approach for this?

I'm thinking something along the lines of UML but I feel that it's a bit overkill for a one-man project.

What are some of the things professionals say is best to do when developing hobby projects?

*Anticipating the votes to close as usual, this isn't argumentative. It's a clear cut answer, and I'm expecting something established. :P*

Comment: put in community wiki then...

Comment: As a general remark: Don't expect that designing your whole application upfront will actually work. It is rather going to be a iterative process where you are analyzing your requirements, design and implement a little bit before you go back to requirements analysis or design.

Answer (score 6):

I try to split the problem usually into two different issues:

- who is involved (this are good candidates for classes)
- what is happening (similarly, this tends to be good methods, and also things that one might want to focus on to establish performance requirements).

For example: when searching for the cheapest car inside a set of possible cars, I'd identify 'cheapest' as something that probably wants to be a separate function, as I may want to change the conditions later, or apply it to SUVs as well, and 'car' and 'set of cars' sounds like good candidates for classes that I'd need in the problem domain.

To establish those:

- search for verbs in the problem description: those make methods
- search for nouns in the problem description: those make classes
- find the constraints, and what they are relevant for: is cheapest a property of something, or rather a result of an operation?

Eventually I move from drawing those relationships further to pseudo-code and small prototypes to play around and learn what other unknown constraints appear in the problem description.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of thing, I usually sketch out the basic UIs, chart out (boxes on paper) a domain model and a database schema. I always start on paper and then if I feel it is necessary I export to visio/basalmiq.

Answer (score 2):

For simple program, I will use paper and pencil to draw a sketch of its UI, make some annotations on it.  It can help me to clarify my idea and confirm my design.

If the program is bigger (more like a complete product I mean), you may need to collect some feedback from others, since one man's thought can not cover everything. The hand drawn sketch still works, invite more people to review it and give you some suggestions, thus you can polish your design a lot.  However if your friend is not around you may need to fax the papaer sketch to them (or maybe scan the paper sketch and send via email).

There are some tools that can help you to create UI prototype, some of them even allow you to run simulation of the UI (like Axare and ForeUI), that will be very useful to collect feedback from others.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like a mini-notepad inside a jacket pocket, to mind dump as soon as possible, I personally switch between mini-UML and dot points. Quick, Simple, Always Accessible.

edit: And I always have a page/area dedicated to specific use cases and actions. This allows me to come back and check if the system can handle each of these.

Comment: dot points? what's that?

Comment: @James: by dot points I'm assuming theraven means lists of points, with a dot or bullet at the start. Like the default look of an HTML <ul> type list.

Comment: yes, a list with dots next to it :) Breaking problem/application into 'areas' and further separating with indentation(lists of lists)

Comment: @James Deville: Usually called "bullet points", I believe.

Comment: dot points are usually followed by word lines.

Comment: I use them with space-delimited letter-groups

Answer (score 1):

It is largely depends on number of things and the most important one is what are you making.

1) The first step to me is to declare what are you making. Sound, simple? sometime is not. List down what you want the program to do. List what is the must-have, what is nice-to-have and what is ok-to-have (not much trouble to include).

2) The second step is to (at your best) identify what is the weakest link for the success of your project. If you are writing WebDB, what you should worry is web UI (transition from a page to another) and data model. If you are writing game, the rules of the game will be important. Or if the game is highly interfactive, then you should think of the interaction the flow of the game.

What you identified here is what you should spend time design it on paper.

Since identifying that will likely to require experience and you may not have (if you do, you will already know what to do, right :-D), you may come back to review it once in a while as project progress.

3) To avoid over-engineering, **focus on modeling for understanding as oppose to modeling as documenting**.

4) Once you understand more, try to create a small program to check if it is possible. If you, identify other critical but risky part.

5) Start small but always think about extension. To me, it is OK to think big but it is risky to do big.

Those are what I do. Hope it will give you some idea. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I'd use UML not because it's the defacto industry standard but because it helps you organize and document your thoughts as you explore a domain (whether personal or business). A free tool is ArgoUML.

I'd mock UIs as another aid in figuring and communicating what you think you'd like to do in your system.  A great free one is Balsamiq Mockups.

And I'd focus on behavior first and data last.  See Rebecca Wirfs-Brock's writings.

Best of luck! Mark

Answer (score 0):

Some of my "tricks":

- I first use mind-mapping (e.g. MindMeister).
- Then, I find the probable "difficult spots" and do some lightweight prototyping

Answer (score 0):

i find sketching out the UI first is very help in finding out exactly what functionality is required. Then I like to make a list for each UI element and what it should do. Once this is done I generally write out a database schema...

Answer (score 0):

This is the order of how I do things:

1) Write a pseudocode in pencil. This where you can brainstorm ideas with yourself and others if necessary.

2)Write the algorithm outlining the objectives and how you will go about accomplishing those objectives.

3)If the project is small, simple and clear to you, you can ommit this step. Else, draw up a flow chart of th application.

4)Lastly, Start coding using your algorithm and flow chart as your guide.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should stick with your final goal, In most cases, the final goal is to deliver your result to your customer, your boss, your colleague.

so all you have to do should be consistent with the goal. release it and deliver it.

I don't think designing on a paper is a good idea, it made  you too lazy to do some practical work. Actually most project was too late to enter into coding phase, many stupid designers or architect were arguing the details that never existed in the war-room for a few weeks. they delayed the project.

actually you should learn more thoughts about test-driven development, it doesn't mean you should completely follow the mode, it is a thought to teach you how to effectively commit yourself in deliver the results.

Finally, I think test-driven is the most effective way to keep your commit into delivering qualified results to customers.

Answer (score 0):

I am a big fan of using SketchFlow to create wireframes and mock ups which really helps the over all design process of web/desktop apps.  You can see it and touch it and prove that your ideas will actually work.  I also like the mind-mapping (MindMeister) mentioned else where.  Lately I try to avoid BDUF (big design up front) specifications these days!

Answer (score 0):

For small code projects I like to just go in and code a version 0, create all the classes I think I'm going to need and try and somewhat get them working together.  I then stop and start over completely.  This usually creates a much better project.

Answer (score 0):

Software is like art, in that it is creative and there are limitless possibilities in the way to solve a problem. As programmers we often jump into the code before designing. Design starts before even looking at technical solutions. These are some steps that should be taken first to help limit the scope of the design.

- Define your goals. These may be your own or may be given to you by a business manager/product manager.
- Identify resource constraints. This could be time, money, hardware or even programming languages that you can use.
- Research environmental constraints that are from the industry or environment your software will be a part of. For example regulations or what users are willing to accept.
- Worry about the future (but don't drive yourself crazy). To the best of your ability make the design scalable from a software level and a functionality level.
- Then start iterating. It is important to try things out and start iterating on design. You will never be able to anticipate everything so you try your best and then move forward.

I wrote a blog post that describes these in more detail using examples from unconventional fields, but applies well to software:

[Design like Einstein and Michelangelo](https://medium.com/@dave.b.kaplan/design-like-einstein-and-michelangelo-fadf2c86e3f7)
[image]